# Text processing / regular expressions? in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a data frame with the following columns.

```
user_id: g17165fd2e0bba9a449857645bb6g3a9a7ef8e6c 

time: 1361553741 

url: a string with an url.
```

The URL, sometime, takes the form `https://SOMETHING.COM/NAME/forum/thread?thread_id=51`.

I want to create a data frame that tells me for each user, between time x and y, how many time he or she visited each thread_id. So, the number of observations is equal to the number of user and the number of columns equal to the number of thread ids + 1(the total views)

The data set is really big, so doing this in parallel is a must.

What is the best way of doing this in R ?

Thanks a lot!

PS: @David create code that generates a data frame like the one I mentioned, and also provided a perfect answer to my question.

```
set.seed(2)
#make junk data
dat <- data.frame(user=1:5,
                                 time=1:20,
                                 url=paste0("https://domain.com/forum/thread?     thread_id=",sample(5,20,T)))
```

Comment: A reproducible example can be a toy example that uses a small amount of made-up data. just enough to illustrate your problem. Anyone who wants to offer a solution is inevitably going to have do this so it may as well be you.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will do my best to provide that code next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this will work for you:

```
> library(plyr)
> library(doMC)
> library(reshape2)
> 
> set.seed(2)
> #make junk data
> dat <- data.frame(user=1:5,
+                   time=1:20,
+                   url=paste0("https://domain.com/forum/thread?thread_id=",sample(5,20,T)))
> head(dat)
  user time                                         url
1    1    1 https://domain.com/forum/thread?thread_id=1
2    2    2 https://domain.com/forum/thread?thread_id=4
3    3    3 https://domain.com/forum/thread?thread_id=3
4    4    4 https://domain.com/forum/thread?thread_id=1
5    5    5 https://domain.com/forum/thread?thread_id=5
6    1    6 https://domain.com/forum/thread?thread_id=5
> #subet within time range
> dat <- dat[dat$time >=1 & dat$time <= 20,]
> 
> #make threadID variable
> dat$threadid <- gsub("^.*thread_id=",'',dat$url)
> 
> 
> #register parallel cores
> registerDoMC(4)
> #count number of thread occurrences for each user (in parallel)
> dat.new <- ddply(dat,.(user,threadid),summarize,threadcount=length(threadid),.parallel=TRUE)
> #reshape data to be in the format you want
> dat.new <- dcast(dat.new,user~threadid,value.var="threadcount",fill=0)
> #add total views
> dat.new$totalview <- rowSums(dat.new[,-1])
> dat.new
  user 1 2 3 4 5 totalview
1    1 1 0 1 0 2         4
2    2 1 1 0 1 1         4
3    3 0 1 1 1 1         4
4    4 2 0 2 0 0         4
5    5 1 0 2 0 1         4
```

Comment: That is beautiful code, thank you very much!